# Zipping files with MSBuild creates unwanted root folder inside zip-file

Tags: msbuild, zip

I use following config to unpack my files into one folder, and then rezip it into a single file:

```html
<Target Name="Build_Package" DependsOnTargets="Build_Test">
  <!-- Unzip artefacts to local workfolder -->
  <unzip ZipFileName="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\MyZip.zip" TargetDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\temp\unzipped" />
  <unzip ZipFileName="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\AnotherZip.zip" TargetDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\temp\unzipped" />
  <!-- Zip files into one single package -->
  <Zip Files="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\temp\unzipped"
        WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\temp\work"
        ZipFileName="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\temp\output\Output.zip" />
</Target>
```

This results in a zip file containing the subfolder *unzipped* which I want to remove. I´ve found the option *RemoveRoot* in older posts, but this is not working for me. I also can´t use the extension *MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Compression.Zip*.

Anyone an idea out there? Thank you! :)

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/10/16/msbuild-zip-task-without-external-dependencies/ or similar: basically create your own zip task using standard .Net code. Or invoke an external program like 7zip.

Comment: Great, that worked for me!